# azure databricks: exceeding approved Total Regional Cores quota

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a "Pay as you Go" Azure subscription.

Currently I have no active resources in this subscription

(all of the resources involved in prior projects have been deleted).

I have created a new Databricks premium resource and proceeded to execute the provided Delta Live Tables example by choosing to create a new DLT pipeline from the example code.

This attempt have failed with the following error:

```
    DataPlaneException: [DLT ERROR CODE: CLUSTER_LAUNCH_FAILURE.CLIENT_ERROR] 
Failed to launch pipeline cluster 0928-153235-l27bxsvs with termination code 

INVALID_ARGUMENT and termination type CLIENT_ERROR: Attempt to launch cluster with 

invalid arguments. databricks_error_message: Operation could not be completed as it 

results in exceeding approved Total Regional Cores quota. Additional details - Dep...
```

I have checked my Azure Compute quotas - there is plenty of availability as I am not currently using any other Compute resources.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a support/billing question

Comment: This (quota/capacity increase) is something that needs to be handled by support, not Stack Overflow (since it's a subscription-level issue, and not a programming question)

Comment: My quota is wide open - no restrictions, no need to increase. Yes I have this error

Comment: Ok, but still... this isn't a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that quotas are used for different resource groups, subscriptions, accounts, and scopes. For instance, the number of cores for a particular region may be restricted by the subscription you have. An error claiming the quota has been exceeded appears if you try to install a virtual machine with more cores than are allowed.

**To check your subscription's Usage + Quotas.**

Choose a subscription >> Settings >> Usage + Quotas. Select `Microsoft.Compute` using the filter.

Verify total regional vCPU consumption here: If the consumption is at capacity, **you must choose Request Increase to raise the region's core limit.** From here only you have `New Quota Request` Option to raise Increase quota limit

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-resource-quota?tabs=azure-cli#solution